# Keep Navigation Links at one section and render it in all other pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, render

I have 100 web pages to my web site.
All web pages has links to other 99 pages.
If i want to add one more page to my web site i have to add new page link to all other page.    I want to keep all page link at one place.
So that i can render all Navigation links from that section.
How can i archive this in MVC 4?
My Number of pages are growing day by day.

Comment: Using Master Page/LayoutPage is the way to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got the question right, but will the use of MasterPages help you out here?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635324/Another-set-of-ASP-NET-MVC-4-tips#tip-02) [this](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/Asp-Net-mvc-4-layout-and-section-in-razor/) must help you

Keeping all the links in _Layout.cshtml and calling the _Layout.cshtml in all pages is the solution.

To call the _Layout.cshtml in other pages use.

```
@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
```